# Image on annotation Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to use my own image as a "pin" and i have about 4 different images. Since i'm using alot of coords, is this a good way to "stack them up"
Thanks in advance.

Code is following:

```
         struct Location {
            let title: String
            let subtitle: String
            let imageName: String
            let latitude: Double
            let longitude: Double
        }

        let locations = [
            Location(title: "ben", subtitle: "The big", imageName: "de.png",   latitude: 56.888214, longitude: 14.779658),
            Location(title: "adam", subtitle: "bervesiell", imageName: "be.png", latitude: 56.588224, longitude: 14.779658),
            Location(title: "david", subtitle: "Downfall", imageName: "ce.png",    latitude: 56.888214, longitude: 14.579668)
        ]

        for location in locations {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = location.title
            annotation.subtitle = location.subtitle
            annotation.imageName = location.imageName
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
            Mapview.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "stack them up".

Comment: Personally, I'd (a) just make `Location` conform to `MKAnnotation`, retire `MKPointAnnotation`, and add the `Location` objects directly to the map view; (b) if there are only four image types, I'd use an `enum` rather than a `String`; and (c) I'd follow Cocoa naming conventions for the map view (start its name with lower case letter).

Comment: @Rob - i think he meant cluster.

Comment: You have to use some kind of library ...search for map cluster git.

Comment: OK. WWDC 2013 [Putting MapKit into Perspective](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/309/) demonstrates this, as well.